# Script to check if an entry present on crontab, if not create new one

Tags: mysql, shell, scripting, cron, solaris-10

I want to make an entry in crontab that will optimize mysql database, so I am writing a script that will check if it is already present, else it will be created.

The problem I'm facing is when I check for entry it is returning many unwanted entries, to be specific all directories, files as output, present in the directory where I am executing the script.

My overall script looks like:

```
check=`crontab -l | grep -i "ABC"`
 if [ -z "$check" ];
 then
     #echo " Adding opt to crontab "
     crontab -l > ./tmpfile

            echo "0 * * * * /bin/bash /usr/bin/mysqlcheck --all-databases -o --user=<user> --password=<pwd> 2>&1  >> ./tmpfile

     crontab ./tmpfile
     rm tmpfile
     echo "ABC has been successfully added to crontab"
     exit 1
 else
    echo "ABC already exists in crontab "
    exit 1
 fi
```

Comment: Is this going into some config mgmt daemon like puppet/chef/cfengine? I don't understand why you need to consistently check crontab for an entry, when once you add it, it should remain unless removed.

Comment: Yes this crontab will be added during configuration of server. our overall script (configuration.sh) takes care of that. It can be executed many times soa check has to be there for the same